I am trying to host a .net core8.0 project on a linux server. I did the configurations. But its still not working
First we installed the .net runtime and sdk to the server. Then I changed my launchsettings http profile to the port that I am going to use. I did not change the other profiles.
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8091",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
}

I also add the builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:8091"); and app.UseForwardedHeaders(); lines to program.cs and removed the app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 
I put the publish files to the root/www/var/myapp folder.
Then I installed the nginx and changed the server_name to my subdomain and add listen:8080 to the configutation file. Also I add this for the location part.

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8091; //my apps port 
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

The https part of this configuration is commented here. I did not change anything there.
I checked if myapp is working with sudo dotnet myapp.dll command. Its working.
Then I created a service named myapp.service

[Unit]
Description=myapp
 
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/root/www/var/myapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /root/www/var/myapp/myapp.dll --urls "http://localhost:8091"
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-myapp
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

then I started and enabled the service with this commands.
sudo systemctl enable NewApp.service
sudo systemctl start NewApp.service
sudo nginx -s reload


The nginx status is active after this. I checked that too.
I also checked with this command sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN if the port is listening. I have my ports in this list.
I also added the ports that I am using to the firewall rules.
Now according to the documentation this should work. But I when I go to my subdomain it says mysubdomain.com took too long to respond.
Do you have any suggestion that might work. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Does mysubdomain.com resolve to the IP(s) of your server? Are both your server and DNS configured w/ IPv4 and IPv6? What does host firewalling look like? Does your hosting provider do any firewalling on top of host based firewalling? Which names/addresses/ports is nginx listening on, check listen in the server section ... add all that info to your question (edit it, not in comments), potentially anonymising IPs/names ...

I solved the issue. It turns out another firewall installed on the server is blocking. When I removed the second firewall the problem was solved. Thanks for your reply.

Good to hear ... 2nd firewall?
